# Valid Rewrite Rule Is Breaking Rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

We have a few rewrite rules in an .htaccess file. There is a single rewrite line of code that is valid but breaks other rules. I'm hoping someone can help decipher this line of code...

```
RewriteRule .? http://www.%1example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

That %1 looks suspicious to me. Is that a valid regex? I'm guessing it's a typo but it validates somehow. We want to delete it (which seems to fix our issues) but we aren't sure if it is doing some magical rewriting in a rare use case.

Any thoughts if %1 is actually doing something?

**UPDATE**
Here is my full code. Some of it redirects traffic to the subdomain "go" to another domain.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
### This next line seems to be broken
RewriteRule .? http://www.%1example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^go(/.*)?$ https://www.example.com$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(.*).aspx$ https://www.anotherexample.com/services [L,R=302]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.anotherexample.com/services [L,R=302]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there some `RewriteCond` before this line?

Comment: @anubhava I've added the full code to my question. Thanks

Comment: `%1` will be empty so you can just remove it from your `RewriteRule`

Comment: @anubhava So the %1 holds the value of the RewriteCond, which in my case is not needed. Thanks